# Searching on the Chrome omnibar with "mysite.com" jumps to search on Twitter, why?

Tags: google-chrome, search

Searching for content on certain site is easy on Google Chrome: you type '***website.com***' and hit the space bar, and a "***search on website.com:***' appears to let you type search terms.

It works with all the sites I know, but strange enough, it doesn't work on my own blog, and I don't know why. When I type '***javipas.com***' on Chrome and hit the space bar, the "***Search on Twitter***:" appears.

Why Twitter and not my blog? Have I something misconfigured in my blog server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simply because your Twitter account is also 'javipas', and you (might?) visit that more than your blog, so Chrome attempts to be clever and helpful by guessing you're going to be using Twitter rather than your blog.

It's a simple fix:

1. Go to chrome://settings/searchEngines
2. Under 'Other search engines', find 'javipas' in the second column, and see which site(s) (in the left column) it relates to
3. Change the left or middle columns as required

So:

- if you saw 'javipas' for both Twitter *and* your blog, either change the keyword (middle column) to something like 'twitter', or if you're never going to search Twitter, just remove it.
- if you saw 'javipas' for only Twitter, either change the keyword to something like 'twitter' and add a new 'javipas' for 'javipas.com'
- if you saw 'javipas' for only your blog, something else is wrong... :/

Comment: You are absolutely right. On "Other search engines there was an entry for Twitter linked to www.javipas.com, and another one for Javipas.com linked to www.javipas.com_ (with underscore). Deleted the first one, edited the second (underscore out), and everything is going fine now. 

Thanks!

Comment: @javipas you're welcome! :)